# Pyhton pandas for manipulate text & inconsistent data

Tags: python, pandas, string, split

how i take specific text from one column in python pandas but inconsistent format for example like this

Area      |       Owners

Bali Island: 4600  | John

Java Island:7200   | Van Hour

Hallo Island : 2400| Petra

and the format would be like this

Area      |       Owners    |   Area Number

Bali Island: 4600  | John     |  4600

Java Island:7200   | Van Hour |  7200

Hallo Island : 2400| Petra    |  2400

Comment: can you provide the DataFrame constructor (or `df.to_dict()`) for clarity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `str.extract`:

```
df['Area Number'] = df['Area'].str.extract('(\d+)$')
```

output:

```
                  Area    Owners Area Number
0    Bali Island: 4600      John        4600
1     Java Island:7200  Van Hour        7200
2  Hallo Island : 2400     Petra        2400
```